# Query MongoDB with regex that ignores punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to query a collection in MongoDB to findOne item who's name matches a string prop via react-router-dom's NavLink. The prop via NavLink has hyphens replacing the spaces, but there are certain names with hyphens in them as well as spaces. This is causing a not found error since my current regex replaces all hyphens with spaces.

On the front end, I'm using NavLink so I'm getting rid of the spaces to follow URL best practices (a url example: `example.com/this-persons-name`) which sends the param `this-persons-name` exactly to my db.

Right now I'm using the following:

```
db.collection('people').findOne({ name: {'$regex': req.params.person.replace(/-/g, ' '), $options: 'i'}})
```

The issue is that if the name has a hyphen in it already (for example: `this-persons name`), it cannot find this person because it searches for `this persons name` instead.

This should work for the following strings:

`thispersonsname`

`this-persons name`

`this-persons-name`

`this persons name`

Comment: Why not just put two hyphens in where there might already be one?

Comment: The code right now replaces all instances of - so it would add two spaces in that case

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by implementing it a different way. I created a `slug` attribute for each item